# Restructuring JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, nested

I have this JSON which I'm parsing using NodeJS and it needs to be restructured into the second JSON which I've added below.

In the first JSON, the `rows` object has two `pages` objects (any number of `pages` objects can be present) which contains all the same keys and values with the exception of `values` and `display` keys.

```
{
  "pages": [
    {
      "label": "SomeLabel",
      "name": "Some",
      "sections": [
        {
          "type": "Repeat",
          "label": "Label 1",
          "name": "Name 1",
          "rows": [
            {
              "pages": [
                {
                  "label": "Label 1",
                  "name": "Name 1",
                  "sections": [
                    {
                      "type": "Flow",
                      "label": "Label 2",
                      "name": "Name 2",
                      "answers": [
                        {
                          "label": "Question Label",
                          "question": "Question",
                          "values": [
                            "Value A"
                          ],
                          "valuesMetadata": [
                            {
                              "display": "Display A",
                              "row": {
                                "columns": []
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "pages": [
                {
                  "label": "Label 1",
                  "name": "Name 1",
                  "sections": [
                    {
                      "type": "Flow",
                      "label": "Label 2",
                      "name": "Name 2",
                      "answers": [
                        {
                          "label": "Question Label",
                          "question": "Question",
                          "values": [
                            "Value B"
                          ],
                          "valuesMetadata": [
                            {
                              "display": "Display B",
                              "row": {
                                "columns": []
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "footer": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In the second JSON the `rows` object has a single `pages` object, inside of which the `values` and `display` keys have multiple values (the non-common values).

```
{
  "pages": [
    {
      "label": "SomeLabel",
      "name": "Some",
      "sections": [
        {
          "type": "Repeat",
          "label": "Label 1",
          "name": "Name 1",
          "rows": [
            {
              "pages": [
                {
                  "label": "Label 1",
                  "name": "Name 1",
                  "sections": [
                    {
                      "type": "Flow",
                      "label": "Label 2",
                      "name": "Name 2",
                      "answers": [
                        {
                          "label": "Question Label",
                          "question": "Question",
                          "values": [
                            "Value A",
                            "Value B"
                          ],
                          "valuesMetadata": [
                            {
                              "display": [
                                "Display A",
                                "Display B"
                              ],
                              "row": {
                                "columns": []
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "footer": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So, I want to know the fast and easy steps to do this. Please let me know the process and methods to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you change it in small example `input` and `output` so they  can  help easily

Comment: Would be easier to read/solve if you explicitly told us the differences between the old and the new json.

Comment: Hey @Scorpioo590, I've edited my post with a shorter JSON and a more descriptive summary. Please help me out!

Comment: @G.aziz please check out my edited question and help me out

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to combine all pages in a single page that holds all information.

This can be achieved using the `Array.reduce` function. `reduce` takes an array and combines all elements to a single value using a function (provided by you) to combine the first two elements until only one is left (i.e. `1 * 2 => new1; new1 * 3 => new2` where `*` represents your function).

Your problem would look something like this:

```
rows[0].pages = rows[0].pages.reduce((currentElement, currentState) => {
    if (!currentState) { // first iteration return first element but make sure display is an array
        currentElement.sections[0].answers[0].valuesMetadata[0].display =
            [currentElement.sections[0].answers[0].valuesMetadata[0].display];
        return currentElement;
    }

    // add values of current element to arrays in current state
    currentState.sections[0].answers[0].values
        .concat(currentElement.sections[0].answers[0].values);
    currentState.sections[0].answers[0].valuesMetadata[0].display
        .concat(currentElement.sections[0].answers[0].valuesMetadata[0].display);
    return currentState;
});
```

`currentElement` is the object of the array that is currently reduced, `currentState` is the intermediate result of the reduction.

## PS:

The object looks like you are way too many arrays where you would not need them. The given code snippet works only for the first element in each array (hence the `[0]`s. If you really do have multiple values in each array you would have to iterate over all of those accordingly.

Comment: Can you please give me an example with loops? That's the part I'm stuck with.